# Android, Functions in Adapter never get called

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

Functions like `onCreateViewHolder()`, `onBindViewHolder()`, `onAttachedToRecyclerView()` never get called. This is what I'm trying to do.

> 1. Switch from `MainActivity` to `RecyclerViewActivity` when `Button1` is clicked, and load `fragment_recyclerview` into `RecyclerViewActivity`

```
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.aboutMeButton:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, AboutMeFragment.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.task1Button:
            intent = new Intent(this, RecyclerViewActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT );
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

> 2. `FragmentViewActivity.onCreate()`

```
FragmentViewActivity.onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recyclerview);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.recyclerViewContainer, RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance()).commit();

    Log.d("AAA", "RecyclerViewActivity.onCreate( )");
}
```

> 3. `RecyclerViewFragment.onCreateView()`:

```
RecyclerViewFragment.onCreateView(){
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
    movieData = new MovieData();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewContainer);

    // Log.d("AAA", "mRecyclerView  = " + mRecyclerView.getId());

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    Log.d("AAA", "getActivity() = " + getActivity().toString());
    Log.d("AAA", "movieList size  = " + movieData.getMoviesList().size());

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MovieDataAdapter(getActivity(), movieData.getMoviesList());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

> 4. `Adapter.getItemCount()` returns 30, however, functions in adapter other than constructor never get called, which leaves me a pure blank
>      screen. I've no idea what's going on

Comment: Look at the `return` statement in your `onCreateView()` method. You're not returning all that stuff you just set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your `View` up in `rootView` and then, instead of returning that `View`, you return `super.onCreateView()`:

Instead of the following in `onCreateView()`:

```
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

You should return the `View` you just set up:

```
return rootView;
```

Comment: OMG... I stayed up all night trying to figure out what's wrong... You are my hero!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**first:**

- don't do any initialization of adapter in **Fragment.onCreateView(,,,)** 
  as name says this method should be used to inflate or create view:

so inflate view:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout, container, false);
}
```

after u create view use **onViewCreated(..)** method to initialize and create adapter:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // here initialize recycler view 
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

and as user13 said  you need to **return inflated view not super created view  !!!!***

then u will avoid such problems

**second:**

- depending on fragment/parent component usage (for example you should use different approach when u implement view pager with state or normal adapter, or you retain fragment) sometimes you can or sometimes can't  hold reference to inflated view (thus return or not once created view) - but as i sad it's depends what approach do you use

Comment: Thank you for your help. I mistakenly return super.onCreateView() instead of rootView as mentioned by user13. Now problem solved